# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) Error while trying to boot standalone react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

Have an use case in project, where i have to load individual html files in electron webview components through electron tabs plugin. Electron as an application boots up first which internally loads react components for rendering the UI. 
Based on user actions, we open new tabs with plugin called electron-tabs which will run each tab as a separate render process. Since electron webview accepts only an html input, we are forced to load each tab webview as local html file.

We want to boot individual react applications as part of local html file which we load to webview .

Sample html file we are using:

```
  <html>
     <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="welcome"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../tabComponents.js"> </script> 
    <script type="text/babel">
    import   Greeting  from "../../tabComponents"

    ReactDOM.render(
        (
            <Greeting />
        ),
        document.getElementById('welcome')
    );
    </script>
</html>
```

Greeting is a basic react component

```
export default class Greeting extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { someKey: 'someValue' };
  }

  render() {
    return <p>{this.state.someKey}</p>;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ someKey: 'otherValue' });
  }
}
```

**Error thrown:**

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
at invariant (react-dom.development.js:49)
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
let HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
let CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: './src/app.jsx',
        tabComponents: './src/components/index.jsx'
    },
    watch: true,
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('app'),
        filename: '[name].js',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'App',
            filename: './index.html',
            template: './src/index.html'
        }),
        new CopyPlugin([
            { 
                from: './src/tabs/*' ,
                to: path.resolve('app')
            },
        ]),
    ]
};
```

Comment: Could it be the extra set of parenthesis in your `ReactDOM.render`? I know you need the comma after `<Greeting />`.

Comment: I don't think so. It is almost similar to having it as ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));